# C# Downloading Image with same name as in URL

Tags: c#, image, download

I've got a method to save an image from requested website url, but it saves image as `wallpaper.jpg`. Is there a possiblity to save an image with the same name as in given url (for example https://i.imgur.com/l7s8uDA.png as a `l7s8uDA.jpg`?

Here's the code:

```
private void DownloadImage(string uri)
{
    string fileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Wallpapers\\wallpaper.jpg";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    // Check that the remote file was found. The ContentType
    // check is performed since a request for a non-existent
    // image file might be redirected to a 404-page, which would
    // yield the StatusCode "OK", even though the image was not
    // found.
    if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
        response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // if the remote file was found, download oit
        using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            do
            {
                bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are giving the filename as wallpaper.jpg then obviously it will be saved as wallpaper.jpg.

Comment: Try `string fileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Wallpapers\\" + uri.ToString() + ".jpg";`?

Comment: @avantvous,using this the filename will be full uri string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the file name from uri this way:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://i.imgur.com/l7s8uDA.png");
var name= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
```

Also if you need file name without extension:

```
var name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri.LocalPath)
```